# php curl_exec function hangs and end with error 500

Tags: php, curl

I have a curl request, it working fine in my localhost, I have uploaded it to server but it hangs and end with error 500 internal server error. If remove the line `echo $output = curl_exec($ch);` It works fine.

```
$url = "https://someserver.com/api/";
$username = "some_user";
$password = "some_apss";
if(!extension_loaded('curl')){
    die("Curl extension not loaded");
}
if(!function_exists('curl_init')){
    die("curl_init not found");
}

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, "$username:$password");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_BASIC);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);     
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 2); 
echo $output = curl_exec($ch);
$info = curl_getinfo($ch);
curl_close($ch);`
```

Comment: of course it works if you remove the `echo $output = curl_exec($ch);` part, because the request is not executed anymore. check the server you are making the request to in a browser and see if it works

Comment: Try writing `$output = curl_exec($ch); echo $output`

Comment: the script is working fine in localhost :(

Comment: @MiqdadAli Does it work when you access the same url in a browser?

Comment: @shiplu.mokadd.im  still issue is there...

Comment: @VladBalmos Its acceble and getting correct output when I access the url through browser and this script is giving correct output from localhost

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That was the issue with my server port. That port was closed. After opening the port its working perfect. Thank you all

Answer (score 1):

It's a server side issue. Not this script's fault.

Comment: Doesn't really matter, the error is server-side. You won't find anything in this script. Check the error logs from the server.

Answer (score 0):

It maybe that the curl extension installed on the server with the script isn't compiled with ssl support.
Execute the folowing code on the server and post back the results:

```
<?php
    $version = curl_version();
    $ssl_supported= ($version['features'] & CURL_VERSION_SSL);
    echo $ssl_supported == CURL_VERSION_SSL;
```

it should output 1. if not you have to install the ssl suport for curl